# How to organize ASP.NET Repeater Digg style paging

Tags: asp.net, pagination, paging

Does anybody know the technique without writing own code for every repeater?

Comment: Bulld a user control with the functionality you require.

Answer (score 0):

see few samples

1. http://www.developer.com/article.php/3646011

   [ASP.NET paging control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652594/asp-net-paging-control)

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972960.aspx

   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ASPNETPagerControl.aspx